# Display Soap Webservices Response in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, response, android-ksoap2

Hi Want display soap web services in Android by using ksoap2. I am using the following code . When I am testing in the Soap Ui Pro it shows ouput xml fine.

```
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
Object result = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
System.out.println("The Result"+result);
```

but I am getting the Exception in my Eclipse Logcat, how can I overcome this in Android

Exception :

```
05-25 15:13:15.105: WARN/System.err(1160): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}wsdl:definitions targetNamespace='urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style'>@1:686 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40546438) 
05-25 15:13:15.115: WARN/System.err(1160):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:273)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually getting **InputStream** in response, you just has to convert it into the String and then you would be able to display it.

Comment: i ma putting  System.out.println("The Result"+result.toString());

Comment: please send sample code to convert that input stream to string in Android

Comment: Do some R&D for "InputStream to String conversion in Android".

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Code:-

```
try {
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    sb.append(httpTransport.requestDump);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(sb.toString()));
```

if u have any query than tell me.